# SQL Server 2016 | Report Services | root folder redirect

Tags: sql-server, redirect, reporting-services, directory, root

I am currently setting up a new report server in our company based on SQL Server 2016. I want our users to access the reports via root url (reports.company.com). As seen in several other discussions from previous SQL Server releases, Report Services doesn't provide an option to redirect the root page in the report subdirectory. Is that still matter of fact in SQL Server 2016? Is there a simple way to implement the redirect without installing IIS on the report server? I think Microsoft should implement this feature in future Releases from SQL Server / Data Tools.

Thanks for your answers/thoughts.

Ivo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [that isn't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-url-ssrs-configuration-manager#URLExamples).

I've dealt with this, and installed a minimal IIS configuration. You only need the HTTP Redirection functionality (and Management Tools, unless you want to configure remotely).

[image: Selecting Server Roles in the Roles and Features Wizard]

[image: Setting up an HTTP Redirect in IIS]